# Conclude that $A$ is invertible if and only if $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ are pairwise different

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ be real numbers and consider the matrix
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \alpha & \alpha ^2 \\
1 & \beta & \beta^2 \\
1 & \gamma & \gamma^2
\end{pmatrix}
\in \ \text{Mat}_3(\mathbb{R})
$$
I have to conclude that $A$ is invertible if and only if $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ is pairwise different (I hope this is the right translation as I have translated from Danish into English).

My attempt:

**First way:** Let $A$ be an invertible matrix. As $A$ is invertible we have that $\det(A) \neq 0 $. But this is only the case if $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ is pairwise different as if they were pairwise equal $\det(A) = 0$

**Second way:** Assume $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$is pairwise different. If this is the case we must have $\det(A) \neq 0$ as if $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ were pairwise equal we would have that $\det(A) = 0$. But if $\det(A) \neq 0$ we must have that A is an invertible matrix.

Thus we conclude that $A$ is invertible if and only if $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ is pairwise different.

Is this approach alright? Can you verify? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct. Yes, if $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are not parwise distinct, then $\det(A)=0$. But you cannot deduce from that that otherwise $\det(A)\ne0$.

You can solve your problem by proving that $\det(A)=(\alpha-\beta)(\beta-\gamma)(\gamma-\alpha)$.

Comment: I actually did prove earlier that $\det(A) = (\alpha - \beta)(\beta - \gamma)(\gamma - \alpha)$. So buy using this I can say that if $A$ is invertible we have that $\det(A) \neq 0$. But $\det(A)$ is only different from $0$ if $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ is parwise distinct. But I am not sure I understand the other way?

Comment: Do I just use that by assuming $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ is pairwise distict to say that this implies $\det(A) \neq 0$? But not using the argument I said before?

Comment: \begin{align}\det(A)=0&\iff(\alpha-\beta)(\beta-\gamma)(\gamma-\alpha)=0\\&\iff\alpha-\beta=0\vee\beta-\gamma=0\vee\gamma-\alpha=0\\&\iff\alpha=\beta\vee\beta=\gamma\vee\gamma=\alpha\\&\iff\alpha\,\beta\text{ and }\gamma\text{ are not pairwise disjoint.}\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating the argument.

- $A$ is invertible iff $\det A \ne 0$
- $\det A = (\alpha-\beta)(\beta-\gamma)(\gamma-\alpha)$. That's the main point.
- $A$ is invertible iff $(\alpha-\beta)(\beta-\gamma)(\gamma-\alpha) \ne 0$ iff $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are pairwise different.